# Meteor: Dynamic pdf generation with pdfKit and FlowRouter

Tags: meteor, pdf-generation, flow-router

I'm using pdfKit and FlowRouter on my meteor App. I would like to generate a pdf file without saving it an the server. In the docs there is an example for that:

```
Router.route('/getPDF', function() {
 var doc = new PDFDocument({size: 'A4', margin: 50});
 doc.fontSize(12);
 doc.text('PDFKit is simple', 10, 30, {align: 'center', width: 200});
 this.response.writeHead(200, {
 'Content-type': 'application/pdf',
 'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=test.pdf"
 });
 this.response.end( doc.outputSync() );
 }, {where: 'server'});
```

But this is for Iron Router usage. As I'm using FlowRouter, I don't know how to display/download the pdf directly to the user without saving the file on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the server side router from meteorhacks [picker](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/picker). Then something along the lines of

```
Picker.route('/generate/getPdf', function(params, req, res, next) {
    var doc = new PDFDocument({size: 'A4', margin: 50});
    doc.fontSize(12);
    doc.text('PDFKit is simple', 10, 30, {align: 'center', width: 200});
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.pdf'
    });
    res.end(doc.outputSync());
});
```

UPDATE: now that `outputSync` is deprecated, use:

```
Picker.route('/generate/getPdf', function(params, req, res, next) {
    var doc = new PDFDocument({size: 'A4', margin: 50});
    doc.fontSize(12);
    doc.text('PDFKit is simple', 10, 30, {align: 'center', width: 200});
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.pdf'
    });
    doc.pipe(res);
    doc.end();
});
```

Comment: It's working great if I type the `localhost:3000/generate/getPdf` in the browser. But If I use a link which goes to the same target, I got the error, that the route does not exist (clicking on the link). After clicking I have to refresh to get the file. I don't understand that.

Comment: try this: `<a href="/generate/getPdf" download="">`

Comment: The `outputSync()` method seems to be deprecated (I guess it was too convenient to use) and I fail to understand how we use it nom :(

Comment: As fabien mentioned above, outputSync is no more.  How can we do this now?

Comment: I never used pdfKit. What method are you supposed to use instead of `outputSync`? Is it based on promises or callbacks?

Comment: This example shows how to return a client-side generated pdf using blobstream.  It seems the new pdfkit uses node.js streams.  I tried ```doc.pipe(res);``` after setting the headers as mentioned in your answer above, but I'm getting back an empty file.

Comment: Try `doc.pipe(res)` and then afterwards `doc.end()`. Try w/o `res.end()`.

Comment: That's it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it now that outputSync() has been removed:

```
Picker.route('/generate/getPdf', function(params, req, res, next) {
    var doc = new PDFDocument({size: 'A4', margin: 50});
    doc.fontSize(12);
    doc.text('PDFKit is simple', 10, 30, {align: 'center', width: 200});
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=test.pdf'
    });
  doc.pipe(res);
  doc.end(res);
});
```